# Nrwl Nx React customize static paths in build index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nrwl-nx

How I can change paths to my bundle files from `/myBundleFile.js` to `/static/myBundleFile.js` in script src in `index.html` that I get from building my React project with [Nx](http://nx.dev)?

I'm using the default React plugin for Nrwl Nx.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `deployUrl` property in the `project.json` for that project.

https://nx.dev/packages/web/executors/webpack#deployurl